# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 6.1.16 $L^p$ spaces

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces

> Problem 6.1.16 - If $0 < p < 1$, the formula $\rho(f,g) = \int |f-g|^p$ defines a metric on $L^p$ that makes $L^p$ into a complete topological vector space.

Attempted proof - Suppose $a,b > 0$ and $0 < p < 1$. For $t > 0$ we have $t^{p-1} > (a + t)^{p-1}$, and by integrating from $0$ to $b$ we obtain $a^p + b^p > (a+b)^p$. Let $E$ and $F$ be disjoint sets of positive finite measure in $X$ and set $a = \mu(E)^{1/p}$ and $b = \mu(F)^{1/p}$ we see that $$\|1_{E} + 1_{F}\|_{p} = (a^p + b^p) > a + b = \|1_{E}\|_{p} + \|1_{F}\|_{p}$$

I am not sure where to go from here, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your last inequality is false (we can have $\|f\|_p = \|g\|_p$ without having $\int |f-g|^p = 0$ (which is equivalent to $f=g$ a.e.)). Hint: By doing a curve discussion, show $(a+b)^p \leq a^p + b^p$ for $a,b \geq 0$. Further hint: You can assume $a = 1$ w.l.o.g. (why?).

Comment: ok let me re-edit my question I think I understand what your saying

Comment: @PhoemueX need some more help if you know how to prove this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Claim:** If $0 < p < 1$ then $(x + y)^p \le x^p + y^p$ for $x,y \ge 0$.

The proof is the standard one for this type of inequalities: following PhoemueX's hint, define $$f(y) = (1 + y)^p - 1 - y^p.$$ Notice that $f(0) = 0$, $f'(y) \le 0$ for $y > 0$ and conclude that $f(y) \le 0$. This implies the claim and hence that $\rho(f,g)$ is a metric (the other two properties are trivial to check).

> **Claim:** $(L^p,\rho)$ is complete.

Follow step by step the proof of completeness for $p \ge 1$, the argument is almost exactly the same.

Comment: what other two properties that you claim are trivial to check?

Comment: Identity (a.e). of indiscernibles and symmetry

Comment: hmm not familiar with those two identities I have not covered metric spaces before but I am somewhat familiar to what they are. Could you provide more details in your answer to prove the first claim I think I have an idea of how to do the second

Comment: If you are trying to prove something, maybe it is worth looking up the definitions first ;) Anyway, symmetry is obvious by the definition of $\rho$, indeed $\rho(f,g) = \int|f - g|^p = \int|g - f|^p = \rho(g,f)$. Finally assume that $\rho(f,g) = 0$. Then $\int|f - g|^p = 0$ and since the integrand is positive, necessarily $|f - g|^p = 0$ a.e.. This implies $f = g$ a.e.

Comment: Stricly speaking, you also need to show that the vector space operations are continuous. This is not too hard to do in this case.

Comment: @PhoemueX: good point, thank you.

Comment: I got it sorry should of just looked it up. The step by step proof of completeness for $p\geq 1$ where is that the argument presented in the book I cannot seem to find it

Comment: No worries :) I don't have Folland's book with me right now, just google for "Riesz Fischer theorem"

Comment: I have the proof in front of me now but I have no idea how to incorporate $\rho$ into it

Comment: Do I need to show that $\rho(f_n,g_n)\rightarrow \rho(f,g)$ in $L^p$?

Comment: Every time there is an $L^p$ norm you should replace it with the distance $\rho$. You can find a proof here: https://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/lp-spaces-for-p-in-01.pdf